# php variable changes on include

Tags: php, include

I have a problem with php when including a file. One of my variables changes when the file is included even if the file does not do any processing; the file is just a class definition.

Here is what my situation looks like (I have just simplified it to make it clearer instead of posting the actual code, which is quite long):

*File **baseclass.php***

```
class BaseClass{
   function doSomething(){
       ....
       foreach($myArray as $arrayKey => $classname){
           require_once($classname.'.php'); 
       }
   }
}
```

*File **extendedclass.php***

```
class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass{
.....
}
```

If you look at the posted code, what happens is that the variable *$arrayKey* changes when the file is included. The included file is only a class definition.
So, in other words, no processing happens when file is included other than that the class is defined.
Has anyone got any tips or ideas about what might be going on and how to fix it?

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What are the values of $myArray before and after including said file?

Comment: do you ask the value at the start of the loop or after the loop. Because the variable $arrayKey will change after each loop.

Comment: I am going to say that it IS doing some processing. To prove a point, include then empty file and by your reckoning it should also change the variable. Look for places in your code where you declare the object, possibly look for constructors or getters if you have them.

Comment: The values of $myArray before and after including said file depends on where the function is called. But as an example, I have an array two with keys 'peter' an 'john'. After including the file $myArray might for example have the value 'mary', even if that key does not exist in the current context. It is obviously set during another loop through another array because the value of the key has a meaning to it. The problem is that I don't understand how this can happen.

Comment: I check the value at the start of each loop, and after calling 'require_once'. Tha variable changes when calling 'require_once' even if it only includes a class definition.

Comment: How can the constructor be called when the class is defined? After I include the file I create a new instance of the class. if the variable had changed after creating a new instance I could understand it, but the variable changes before that. It changes when I call 'require_once'